# How to encrypt data and store in Sqlite Android

Tags: android, sqlite, encryption

I have created `SQLite` database in android.

Here I decided to use *encryption*. I know about sqlite but I don't know how to implement sqlite *encryption* method, the data that is saved in database needs to be encrypted 
and while retrieving data it should be *decrypted*.

Comment: Check: http://sqlcipher.net/about

Comment: If you keep the encryption key on the device it is not significantly more secure than without encryption.

Comment: SQLChiper for Android is out (:

Comment: Thanks for the help, can you please provide some example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [SQLChiper for Android](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/) for `AES` 256-bit encryption for *.db* files which i suppose is easier than handling *encryption* and *decryption* for each database query